# is it possible to write Gram matrix by a system of 3 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Given a Gram matrix G 3x3 = {{25,-14,-9},{-14,12,14},{-9,14,25}} is there such a system of 3 vectors in R^3 whose gram matrix is ​​equal to G.
I have a stupid idea to write down 6 equations (from Gram matrix rule), but I don't know what to do next. IS there any algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please, make an effort to type the formulas (i.e. the matrix) properly: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check whether your matrix is [symmetric positive-semidefinite](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix). Then, you can use [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) to compute the vectors.

Comment: that a supa-dupa theorem, I never heard about it. But I suppose my Professor will not accept this solution, since I am 1year and we are certainly not passed this yet. Anyway, thanks! I will try to describe 'simple' solution, if I am succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is 256 = 16^2, so there is a chance this can be done with just integers.

$$
  \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-4 &  - 3 &  0 \\ 
 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
 0 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
  \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-4 &  2 &  0 \\ 
 -3 & 2 & 3 \\ 
 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
25 &  - 14 &  - 9 \\ 
 - 14 & 12 & 14 \\ 
 - 9 & 14 & 25 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$